# How to read CPU temperature into Arduino

Tags: arduino, sensor, temperature, cpu

I'm not sure about this and if it is possible. I need to read CPU temperature (normal computer) into an Arduino. This could be possinble (at least I think) by connect some kind of sensor that can be placed between heatsink and cpu, where the thermal paste is placed. Or, second option is to read values from the system somehow, or from the motherboard. I hope I'm not talking about stupid things. I need some advices about this.

Comment: Easiest way I think would be putting a thermistor as close as possible to your core, record the offsets of your readings with the thermistor and temps given by the system, make into a table, etc.. BUT, this smells a lot like a XY problem..

Comment: "Openhardwaremonitor" is probably the program you want for Windows.

Comment: Slap a thermistor on it, measure the voltage and your good to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a lot easier to read directly from the system. This of course depends on what operating system the computer is running but this can be easily read using terminal commands (and most likely easy with cmd prompt). For example on OSX You can get temperatures using [istats](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54329/can-i-get-the-cpu-temperature-and-fan-speed-from-the-command-line-in-os-x) and on linux you can use [lm-sensors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/779819/cpu-temperature-embedded-in-bash-command-prompt)

My suggestion would be to run a Python script that executes bash commands to read the cpu temperature and then send the data over serial to the arduino.

I don't think using your own sensor would be a good solution seeing as it would be messy and would probably give less accurate results than the onboard sensor.

Comment: I think that this is a good idea. I'm using windows as os. But why Phyton?

Comment: It would just be my personal preference. It is really easy to execute terminal commands and setting up a serial lines in python is really straightforward.